# sudo vi /ect/network/interfaces brings up an empty file

Tags: server

I've been trying to get my Ubuntu server running and I've learned that I need to make my IP static, so I tried doing it using `sudo vi /ect/network/interfaces` and this pulled up

[image]

then I press D and this comes up

[image]

and I tried it with `sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf`

to edit the other file and it did the exact same thing it just went to the second part with a different file name....

Then I went into webmin and tried editing the file `/ect/network/interfaces` (only this file) and I can edit it in webmin. so does anyone have any info/solutions on how to fix this? I am running on a desktop with Windows 10 and this is 16.04 running on a virtual machine

---

This is what happened when I typed sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf
[image]

Comment: `/etc/network/interfaces`, not `/ect/...`

Comment: also this is what i changed the file in webmin too (made the ip addresses stars) # This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo enp0s3
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
iface enp0s3 inet static
 address ***.***.*.***
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 network ***.***.*.*

Comment: please [edit] your question to add information instead of commenting on it

Comment: If you want to set up a static IP, I believe it's better to use your graphical Network Manager utility, especially if you already use it (for WiFi for example)

Comment: @xhienne The OP is setting up an Ubuntu server, there is most likely no graphical Network Manager in that case.

Comment: @AdrienBeau You may be right (I didn't notice that detail). Especially for a VM. But I know a lot of people that choose Ubuntu as a server for its graphical interface. If this is not the case here, computersinlife, ignore  my comment.

Comment: Windows has something called Snipping Utility. You should use that to take screenshots instead of your phone.

Answer (score 7):

Your command contains a typo. You typed `ect`:

```
sudo vi /ect/network/interfaces
```

You meant `etc`:

```
sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

So `vi` tries to edit inside the `ect` directory which does not exist, so you get the `[New DIRECTORY]` prompt.

Your second command should have worked (no typo), but normally `/etc/resolv.conf` is a symbolic link to a file you should not edit by hand. You should have seen this on your screen, maybe with different values for `nameserver` and `search`:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search lan
```

You said you ended up with "the second part", which is quite simply a normal `vi` screen with an empty file. Maybe something else edited the file and left it empty?

Anyway, correct your typo, edit `/etc/network/interfaces` (copy/paste the full name of the file to avoid typos), and everything should be fine.

Comment: i typed sudo vi /etc/rosolv.conf and the only text that came up was

Comment: # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8) and the last/second line says                                                       #       DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN

Comment: OK, fine. Not a problem: you need to edit `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: what do i need to do to that file?

Comment: This is where you can put your static IP address. As per your question, it is the first file you tried to edit.

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit /etc/network/interfaces. I've only used nano, so typically the command will be

`sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`

Here's a example config.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.0.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.0.0.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

For the changes to take affect, you can run the following

```
sudo ifdown [interface]; sudo ifup [interface]
```